# How to find order of convergence in finite element method computationally when exact solution is unknown for time dependent problem

Tags: finite-element, nonlinear-equations

Say for heat equation or Burgers equation with nonlinear boundary condition. Exact solution is unknown. 
So I am taking for small mesh size the discrete solution as exact solution. Then how to write the coding part for $L^2$ and $H^1$ error in Matlab?

Comment: Welcome to SciComp.SE. If your question is about how to code something, this might be the wrong place to ask. If not, then I think that you can rephrase your question.

Answer (score 1):

If the exact solution is unknown, then yes you have to take the smaller grid as reference. Then you run your simulation with different mesh size, each one varying by a factor 2 and you compute the norm $L^2$ as :
$$
\vert \vert u-u_{ref}\vert \vert_{L^2} = \sum_{i=1}^n \sqrt{(u(i)-u_{ref}(i))^2}
$$
with $n$ the number of grid nodes for the considered mesh. Finally, you plot this quantity in respect to the factor size in a log-log plot and the slope of the curve will give you the order. I can suggest you to look at this NASA website : http://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/wind/valid/tutorial/spatconv.html

Don't remember for $H^1$.

An applied mathematician tolds me once that the order of convergence for a specific method is dependent on the choice of the norm, it may be more relevant for a specific case to compute the order with the $L^{\infty}$ norm or the $L^1$ norm or whatever norm you decide to define. If anyone has an expertise here, it would be great to have a detailed explanation.

**EDIT** : see also https://www.kth.se/social/upload/52ea4f1ff2765454c236fe79/ConvRate.pdf